# CSS issue - disable scroll on x-direction and fit in the center

Tags: html, css

One of the pages in my website is having an issue where the page is scrollable on x-position which results the content to be cutoff. Other pages on this website is fine except for this one. I've fiddled with the classes and margin but for some reason I can't get it right.

(Live preview on responsive mode [mobile phones]: http://hub.mymagic.my/idea/frontend/explore)

Need another eye for this. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

using chrome's toggle device toolbar + inspect source code, i was able to trace this CSS line on frontend.css:

```
.cbp .cbp-item {
    width: 350px;
...
...
...
}
```

It seems that this width is making the content to extend beyond the size of mobile browser thus making it appear to be scrollable. I guess you can play or override this value somewhere or replace it with `max-width` attribute.